# How do i understand the following DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am very new to Power BI, need help in understanding the following codes as I am not able to understand the using of `AllExcept`:

```
1) Trial Col = CALCULATE(SUM('Trial Table 2'[Total Sales]),FILTER(ALL('Trial Table 2'[Region Group]),'Trial Table 2'[Region Group] = "Low Region"), ALLEXCEPT('Trial Table 2','Trial Table 2'[Region Group]))

2) Trial Col = CALCULATE(SUM('Trial Table 2'[Total Sales]),FILTER(ALL('Trial Table 2'[Region Group]),'Trial Table 2'[Region Group] = "Low Region"), ALLEXCEPT('Trial Table 2','Trial Table 2'[Customer Group]))
```

[image: Data]

Comment: Check the auto-exist. You can watch this video to understand better auto-exist idea. Engine is merging both filters as one. Every Filter in DAX is a Table, that mean you put two sets of value and only these from both are accepted

https://www.sqlbi.com/tv/auto-exist-on-clusters-or-numbers-unplugged-22/

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and formatted so it's easier to read and added comments so you can understand each piece. Please let me know if you have any questions and check out the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/allexcept-function-dax) for ALLEXCEPT which is the trickiest piece to understand here.

```
Trial Col =
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Trial Table 2'[Total Sales]), // Give me the total sales
        FILTER(
            ALL('Trial Table 2'[Region Group]),
                'Trial Table 2'[Region Group] = "Low Region"), // Where the region is = Low Region
            ALLEXCEPT('Trial Table 2',
                'Trial Table 2'[Region Group]) // Ignore all other filters/slicers except for Region Group.
)

Trial Col =
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Trial Table 2'[Total Sales]), // Give me the total sales
        FILTER(
            ALL('Trial Table 2'[Region Group]),
                'Trial Table 2'[Region Group] = "Low Region"), // Where the region is Low Region
            ALLEXCEPT('Trial Table 2',
                'Trial Table 2'[Customer Group]) // Ignore all other filters/slicers except for Customer Group.
)
```

Comment: thanks for replying. What i am confused with is, how all and allexcept will work, when used in one DAX expression. Basically, how the row context, filter context and context transition will work in above case. Row context is implicit as i am adding a column